# Cocoa Frameworks: Using one framework inside of another

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm building a framework (main) which uses another framework (sub). Main framework will be used then in different apps. 
The main framework target builds without errors. However, if I try to build an App which uses the main framework I receive an error -> Class in the main framework cannot find/import the sub framework... 
How can I configure main framework so that it will find the sub framework?

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but there's some discussion of this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516373/can-i-include-a-framework-in-another-framework

Comment: Did not understand your solution, you just ran the build script? And what is in this case "general case"?

Comment: Here is the answers with screenshots that how we can create a framework inside another framework http://stackoverflow.com/a/27638841/1582217

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an Umbrella framework in iOS sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you want to create one framework inside another. It is called "Umbrella framework" and it's not a good idea.

Documentations says:

> **Don't Create Umbrella Frameworks**
>
> While it is possible to create umbrella frameworks using Xcode, doing
>   so is unnecessary for most developers and is not recommended. Apple
>   uses umbrella frameworks to mask some of the interdependencies between
>   libraries in the operating system. In nearly all cases, you should be
>   able to include your code in a single, standard framework bundle.
>   Alternatively, if your code was sufficiently modular, you could create
>   multiple frameworks, but in that case, the dependencies between
>   modules would be minimal or nonexistent and should not warrant the
>   creation of an umbrella for them.

You can use one framework inside another, but both frameworks must be included to your app target and must be copied to /Contents/Frameworks/ directory of your app bundle. Also you must set `Installation directory` to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` for both frameworks.

Comment: Oh my god after all of the convoluted `umbrella`, `sub-umbrella`, `reexport_framework`, `allowable_client` nonsense… I think your **blissfully simple method** of dumping them all in the main executable's frameworks folder... And simply linking away like usual ... To your hearts extent..actually works… _I think_