# Adding frameworks to framework in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have an Xcode 4 project which has just one target: a framework.
How can I add a framework (in particular, OSAKit) to this project? I know how to add frameworks to apps, but I can't do the same with my own framework.

Comment: This question has some information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516373/can-i-include-a-framework-in-another-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way: I click on the target, then I click on "Build phases" and I go to "Link binary with libraries"